# Android: I have a fixed header for a listview but the "glow effect" is only for the listview

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a layout similar to the people app, so I have a list with a fixed header at the top. I define the header on top of the listview inside a relative layout but the "glow effect" at the top of the list is only for the listview and not the whole layout.

This is what I have:
[image]

and this is what I want:
[image]

This is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/last_updated"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/nice_blue" 
        />

    <View style="@style/HeaderDivider"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/status_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I'd like to have the glow at the top of the header, not the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glow effect in both examples are functioning the same.

What is happening within the People application is that it is also a `ListView` just like yours. The effect happens in the same place. The *Me*, *#*, *A*, etc headers are actually inside the *ListView*.

**Option 1**

To do what you are looking to do, put a header in the `ListView`, you'll also need to create a custom `ListView`. This means **extending** `ListView`.

It sounds more challenging than it is, but you should be able to find a number of examples online. Look for examples that *extend* a `ListView` rather than creating a *custom* `ListView`.

The general idea is that you'll add in a `TextView` into the the `View` of the `ListView` that will act as your header. This will put the header text *Last updated at* inside of the `ListView` view that you've created and since it is inside, it will be included underneath the glow.

**Option 2**

You may be able to use the [addHeaderView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) or [addHeaderView(View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) methods on the `ListView` itself.

I believe this will add a header row inside the `ListView`, but I've never used this so I can't say for sure how it works. This may be easier, but will be less flexible.

Comment: I also added a method **Option 2** to the answer that _may_ work and be easier for you to do. However I've never used it so I'm not sure how it works exactly.

Comment: for **Option 2** you can do it like this:`View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
    R.layout.YourXmlHeader, null);` then `yourListView.addHeaderView(header);`

Comment: I've already done option 2 and the header scrolls with the listview so doesn't stay at the top when you scroll. Thanks for the help though

Comment: So in the end I used this excellent library called stickylistheaders here https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders. Thanks for the help!